# Form target be nested frame?

Tags: html

```
<Form bla bla...target="something">
</form>
```

Is it possible that "something" is a nested frame or another object, that does NOT require an additional html file to be referred to?

Purpose is to submit form's content(post) to php file, but the result to be loaded in this same file(if it would be a frameset and so the target to be the inner frame, it would require an additional file). How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not understanting your question
but zou can post to an iframe by using it's name:

```
<Form bla bla...target="iFramenName"></form>
```

meanwhile you must have this iFrame in your Document

```
<iframe src="" name="iFrameName" id="iFrameName".../>
```

and you don't need an additional file

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

```
<form ... target="frame_name">
```

If you're still confused, check out the great examples at this page:

http://www.resource-centre.net/html-using-frames-to-divide-up-a-page